# Resize root partition in GParted

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I installed Ubuntu and during installation I formatted all the hard disk by mistake. Now I am trying to partition it (with `GParted`), but for some reason I can't, when I click on `resize`, the size of the partition is not editable. I think I should've partitioned it before the installation. Here is a snapshot from `GParted`. 
[image]

[image]

Do I have to reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: -1 for dumping full sized screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot resize a mounted `ext*` partition. Boot the Ubuntu installer disk, choose *Try Ubuntu* and run GParted without mounting your hard disk.